# Animate ViewPager.setAdapter() method

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

This is a little complicated to explain. In my layout I have a ViewPager component. In my MainActivity I initialize it and set an custom FragmentStatePagerAdapter on it:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerMain);
mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

This is my Custom ScreenSlidePagerAdapter:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.init(position, candidateID);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

The ScreenSlidePageFragment is initialized with some ImageViews. So far so good. What happens next is, I update the the content, meaning the ImageViews in the PageViewer and use

> mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

to update. I can see the new ImageViews on the screen, as I reset the adapter. Exactly this sudden change is what I want to avoid. When the ViewPager refreshes its content, I want this to be animated. A little like on tinder, when you dismiss a person. Again: I'n not talking about the swipe animation between the ImageViews after the adapter has been set, but as I change/rebuild the adapter itself.

I tried many things, but I just dont know where to apply the animation and to which object. Do you have an idea, how refreshing the adapter can be animated in a way like fragments are animated when they are replaced?

Comment: did you look at the function startUpdate(ViewGroup container)

Comment: Yes I did, but I in this case, I dont have a fragment. This doesnt help me any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of try&error I solved it by adding a "RootFragment" for the first ItemPosition, replacing this Fragment with my real first Fragment and as I replace using the common FragmentTransaction setting the setCustomAnimations to it.

I think there are better ways of doing this, in most cases when the PageViewer is set, it stays like that. Thats why I had so much difficulties solving this issue. If you want to read more about PageViewer you should read this:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter